# How to set the LMAXMIX tag in VASP for the material BaLaMn2O6?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, dft-u

I am trying to do DFT+U calculation for the material BaLaMn2O6 . As per the vaspwiki it is recommended to set `LMAXMIX = 4` (d-elements) and `LMAXMIX = 6` (for f-elements) to obtain fast convergence to ground state. In my situation, I have both f-block element(La) and d-block element (Mn).

How should I set the `LMAXMIX` tag in the DFT+U calculation in proper way?

**INCAR file**

```
Global Parameters\
ISTART =  1            (Read existing wavefunction; if there)\
LREAL  = Auto          (Projection operators: automatic)\
ENCUT  =  600        (Cut-off energy for plane wave basis set, in eV)\
PREC   =  High       (Precision level)\
LWAVE  = .TRUE.        (Write WAVECAR or not)\
LCHARG = .TRUE.        (Write CHGCAR or not)\
ADDGRID= .TRUE.        (Increase grid; helps GGA convergence)\
EDIFF = 1.0E-06 \
ALGO=Fast\
Lattice Relaxation\
NSW    =  55          (number of ionic steps. Make it odd.)\
ISMEAR =  0            (gaussian smearing method )\
SIGMA  =  0.05         (please check the width of the smearing)\
IBRION =  2            (Algorithm: 0-MD; 1-Quasi-New; 2-CG)\
ISIF   =  2            (optimize atomic coordinates and lattice parameters)\
EDIFFG = -1.0E-03      (Ionic convergence; eV/AA)\
PREC   =  High         (Precision level)\
\
LDAU = True             #switches on DFT+U  \
LDAUJ = 0 0 0 0         # J values (For LDAUTYPE=2 , Ueff = U-J)\
LDAUL = 3 -1 2 -1       #l-quantum number (-1 : no U)\
LDAUPRINT = 1           # 0:silent, 1: write occupancy matrix to OUTCAR)\ 
LDAUTYPE = 2            #The simplified approach to the DFT+U , introduced by  Dudarev et al.\
LDAUU = 4.0 0 3.0 0     # for Ba:0 , Mn:5.0 , Sb:0, F:0 ( U values in eV) \
LMAXMIX = 6             # 4 for d-electrons, 6 for f-electrons\
LASPH = .TRUE.   \
```

**POSCAR file**

```
generated by phonopy\
   1.0\
     3.9178000000000002    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000\
     0.0000000000000000    3.9178000000000002    0.0000000000000000\
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    7.8070000000000004\
La Ba Mn O\
   1    1    2    6\
Direct\
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000\
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000\
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.7548999999999999\
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.2451000000000001\
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000\
  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.7626999999999999\
  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.7626999999999999\
  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.2373000000000001\
  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.2373000000000001\
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
```

Comment: If you want to include only the d orbitals in the projection, you can set LMAXMIX = 4. This would exclude the f orbitals from the projection. If you want to include both the d and f orbitals in the projection, you should set LMAXMIX = 6. This would include both the f and d orbitals. Pay attention that You should always consider what electrons the elements you are studying have in their valence shell regardless of the block they blong to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But Mn has electronic configuration :  [Ar] 3d5 4s2 and for La the configuration  : [Xe] 5d1 6s2 , here the valence shell electrons are both s-orbitals. That means should i not use the DFT+ U scenario or should i use the U parameter for only Mn ?

Comment: @JaafarMehrez can you please give me a reference for setting LMAXMIX =6 to include both d- and f- electrons ? Like where such example is used or any example mentioned in vaspwiki or in vasp community . Just to be sure. Thank You !!

Comment: @JaafarMehrez can i set LMAXMIX = 6 2 4 2 ,for elements in POSCAR i.e, La Ba Mn O respectively ?

Comment: From vaspwikit the tag LMAXMIX takes one integer, it states exactly LMAXMIX controls up to which l-quantum number the one-center PAW charge densities are passed through the charge density mixer and written to the CHGCAR file. I think by choosing the value to 6 you already included other l-quantum numbers.

Comment: LMAXMIX is a single integer value according to the vaspwiki, unlike LDAUL or LDAUJ which is integer array so that it can take several values, LMAXMIX is an increamental, so in your case as you have f-block elements and you want to describe effect from that element correctly you just need to set LMAXMIX=6, you should consider that be computationaly heavier for sure

Comment: We have a VASP chat room here if you need more space to talk!

Comment: @JaafarMehrez Thank you for the clarification !!

Comment: @NikeDattani could you please include us to the VASP chat room ? Thank you !!

Comment: Based on your last reply to @JaafarMehrez it looks like a lot was clarified for you. Were you able to figure out the answer to your original question now?

Comment: This is the VASP room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109983/vasp

Comment: @NikeDattani yes I figured out my problem. Thanks a lot to you guys !!

Comment: @JaafarMehrez would you like to write an answer, now that we know that your comments helped the OP with their initial problem? It would be nice for this question to now be removed from the "unanswered" queue, which ideally would only include questions for which people still actively need an answer.

Comment: @NikeDattani Sure, I will provide a full answer based on the comments

Answer (score 2):

DFT+U is an advanced computational method developed specifically to enhance the accuracy of describing systems containing strongly correlated *d* or *f* electrons. These systems, such as antiferromagnetic NiO, often pose challenges for conventional LDA and GGA functionals, which tend to provide inaccurate description.

When applying DFT+U in VASP, the parameter LMAXMIX plays a crucial role in controlling the range of l-quantum numbers for which the one-center PAW charge densities are processed and saved in the CHGCAR file. Unlike LDAUL or LDAUJ, which accept multiple values as an integer array, LMAXMIX is a single integer value. To accurately capture the effects of f-block elements in your system, it is recommended to set LMAXMIX=6. Thus, by choosing the value to 6, you already included other l-quantum numbers. However, it's important to note that this choice can lead to increased computational complexity.